# Kotlin JPA One-To-Many @ElementCollection attempts to save duplicates resulting in constraint violations

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, kotlin

I have the following entity defined (simplified)...

```
@Entity(name = "metrics")
data class MetricsEntity(
    val name: String,
    // ... other properties omitted for clarity
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "event_name")
    @Column(name = "event_count")
    @CollectionTable(name = "metric_event", joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "metrics_id")])
    val events: MutableMap<String, Int>,
)
```

The idea here is that for every entry in the metrics table we record counts of events and we end up with a table containing entries like this...

```
 metrics_id |            event_name             | event_count 
------------+-----------------------------------+-------------
   15647624 | Launched                          |           1
   15647624 | Registration_successful           |          10
   15647624 | Registration_failed               |           2
   15647624 | History_viewed                    |           1
```

In the code we load the metrics entities using something like this...

```
val metrics = metricsRepository.findByProperties(properties)
```

...to get a single metric. The selection criteria here have been simplified but suffice to say we get one metric instance from this query. the repository here is defined as...

```
interface MetricsRepository : CrudRepository<MetricsEntity, Long> {
   ...
}
```

Now we either update the events map to add a new count of one of increment an existing count using the following code...

```
metrics.events[eventName] = (it.events[eventName] ?: 0) + 1
metricsRepository.save(it)
```

This works the vast majority of the time but every now and again the call to save throws a constraint violation called metric_event_constraint on the above table which is defined as...

```
ALTER TABLE metric_event ADD CONSTRAINT metric_event_constraint UNIQUE (metrics_id, name);
```

This seems to suggest that the save operation is saving a new row when a row already exists. Looking at the log is suggests that I am getting collisions between multiple threads trying to modify the same count...

```
08:58:18.466  INFO 3 --- [TaskExecutor-11] incr count for event Launched, count 1
08:58:18.487  INFO 3 --- [cTaskExecutor-4] incr count for event Launched, count 1
08:58:18.618 ERROR 3 --- [cTaskExecutor-4] incr count failed for request
08:58:24.623  INFO 3 --- [TaskExecutor-94] incr count for event Launched, count 2
08:59:14.951  INFO 3 --- [askExecutor-126] incr count for event Launched, count 3
```

...here the first event works and increments the count, the second one fails and doesn't (constraint violation caught) and the 3rd and 4th work fine. Total count is 3 when we wanted 4. It looks to me like the 1st and 2nd event collided.

So the question is firstly do you think that this summary is correct? Secondly, how do I make it work ;)? My assumption is that I need to lock the metric entity so how would I go about that using the framework of crud repositories and entity classes used?

The database behind this is Postgres.

Regards,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

> So the question is firstly do you think that this summary is correct?

That's quite possible.

> how do I make it work ;)?

You can lock the entity while fetching (using the second argument to `EntityManager.find()` if interacting with `EntityManger` directly, or the `@Lock` annotation on Spring Data repository method. For your scenario, I'm guessing you'll want optimistic locking, which means you'll need to add a `@Version` field to your entity (you might also want to retry with a pessimistic lock if the optimistic one fails, but if collisions are scarce, purely optimistic locking is probably the way to go).

Of course, if you want both modification attempts to succeed, you'll need to capture and handle the locking exception by retrying the operation (I believe Spring repos will wrap it into a `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException`, but you'll have to check).